# Page Not Found: /<int:pk>.pk

Tags: python, django

Can someone tell me why the urls generated from clinking the template link is /.pk. I am trying to understand how the urls work. New to Django here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 647, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 357, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 717, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\hanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Not Found: /<int:pk>.pk
[10/Jan/2019 00:18:34] "GET /%3Cint:pk%3E.pk HTTP/1.1" 404 16594
```

Template

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'details' pk=Testimony.id %}">{{testimony.Title}}</h1>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  ...
    path('<int:pk>/$', views.detail, name='details'),
]
```

views.py

```
def details(self, pk):
    print('1')
    testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, pk= pk)
    print('2')
    return render(request, 'details.html', {'testimony': testimony})
```

Comment: Remove the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Like in your last question, you are confusing the new syntax for `path()` and the regex syntax for `re_path()`/`url()`.

`path()` does not take regexes, so you should not include `$` at the end. Change it to:

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='details'),
```

Since your template context is `{'testimony': testimony}`, you should use lowercase `testimony` in the url tag:

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'details' pk=testimony.id %}">{{testimony.Title}}</h1>
```

After making changes to your code/templates, make sure you have saved any changes and restarted your server to make sure you are running the code you think you are.